# How do I implement an ajax spinner in my Rails 4 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm relatively good at Rails 4, but not very apt at Javascript (something I'm trying to work hard at presently). One of my biggest frustrations is not being able to implement an ajax spinner (or any ajax functionality for that matter) into my application.

Here's my code

show.html.erb

```
<% if @category.name == "motivation" %>
  <div class="spinner"></div>
  <div class="category-jumbo-1" style="height: 400px; margin-top: -20px"    onload = loadDoc()>   
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's my css

```
//css for spinner
.spinner {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
 }

 @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
 }

 //css for background image
 .category-jumbo-1 {
    background: url("motivation.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Here's my images.js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".spinner").hide();
    function loadDoc() {
      $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $(".spinner").show();
      }).ajaxComplete(function() {
        var $loading = $(".spinner");
        setTimeout(function(){
        $loading.hide();
      },1000);
    }); 
  }
});
```

The spinner appears above the image but does not disappear. It becomes part of the layout. I know this is a rudimentary issue for Rails developers, but ajax has been a thorn in my life since I started working on Rails.

Comment: How do you use `loadDoc`?

Comment: Also insert some `console.log` statements and observe output. Does `ajaxStart` gets invoked? But not `ajaxComplete`? Is the request successfull and not an error (in network tab)?

Comment: To echo advice, learning to use the debugger console, especially breakpoints, will help immensely.